# How to sum values from csv file with Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have a Csv file with several columns. The 4th Column has a format that I want to parse. String `str` below would be one line of the file:

```
str = "108,882,xyz, { Abc:{-} Val1:{6845} Val2:{653} llsh:{0} xTime: {2018-11-10 09:56:12} Yub:{Rtv} Val1:{807} Val2:{153} llsh:{0} xTime: {2018-11-10 09:59:05}A Wbc:{57} Val1:{441} Val2:{875} llsh:{0} xTime: {2018-11-10 10:13:12:22}"
```

For this 4th column I'd like to sum all Val1 and Val2 present within the string and show the first and last date as a new column. If Val1 and Val2 appear only once, then there is sum to do and output would be the values of Val1, Val2 and xTime.

The output would be:

```
Col1, Col2, Col3, Val1,  Val2 , xTime
108,  882,  xyz,  8093,  16821, 2018-11-10 09:56:12 - 2018-11-10 10:13:12:22
```

I'm trying with CSV.parse.

```
require 'csv'

CSV.parse(str)

For 4th column do
       //Parse
```

How can I do this in Ruby?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The essence of this problem is extracting the desired information from the part of the string that follows `"108,882,xyz, "`, as opposed to how a CSV string is to be parsed, so I will confine my attention to the former.

```
r = /
    Val1:\{                      # match string
    (\d+)                        # match > 0 digits in capture group 1 
    \}\ +Val2:\{                 # match string
    (\d+)                        # match > 0 digits in capture group 2
    \}\ +[^\}]+\}\ +xTime:\ +\{  # match string
    (.+?)                        # match > 0 characters lazily in capture group 3
    \}                           # match string
    /x                           # free-spacing regex definition mode
```

This regular expression is conventionally written as follows:

```
/Val1:\{(\d+)\} +Val2:\{(\d+)\} +[^\}]+\} +xTime: +\{(.+?)\}/
```

Notice that when using free-spacing mode space characters would be stripped out by the parser if they were not protected in some way. There are a few ways of protecting them. I have chosen to escape each space character. Free-spacing mode has the advantage that it makes the regular expression self-documenting.

```
a = str.scan(r)
  #=> [["6845", "653", "2018-11-10 09:56:12"],
  #    [ "807", "153", "2018-11-10 09:59:05"],
  #    [ "441", "875", "2018-11-10 10:13:12:22"]]
```

```
val1, val2, (f,*,l) = a.transpose
  #=> [["6845", "807", "441"],
  #    [ "653", "153", "875"],
  #    ["2018-11-10 09:56:12", "2018-11-10 09:59:05", "2018-11-10 10:13:12:22"]]
val1
  #=> ["6845", "807", "441"] 
val2
  #=> ["653", "153", "875"] 
f #=> "2018-11-10 09:56:12" 
l #=> "2018-11-10 10:13:12:22"
```

```
def convert(arr)
  arr.map(&:to_i).sum
end
```

```
convert(val1)
  #=> 8093 
convert(val2)
  #=> 1681 
"%s - %s" % [f,l]
  #=> "2018-11-10 09:56:12 - 2018-11-10 10:13:12:22"
```

See [String#scan](https://ruby-doc.org//core-2.6.3/String.html#method-i-scan).

Comment: Hi Cary. It works excellent. Very clean code and didactic solution. This time I understood almost all your code. I'll continue study your regex because the csv has other columns that I need to parse with similar format. The only thing I saw out of my knowledge was the assignment `(f,*,l)`. Additionally, if there is only one val1, val2 and date an extra `-` is added. I can remove it but which technique would you use to do that?

Comment: If there is just one triple, `val1, val2, (f,*,l) = a.transpose #=> [["6845"], ["653"], ["2018-11-10 09:56:12"]]`, with `f #=>  "2018-11-10 09:56:12"` and `l #=> nil`. Therefore, you could write `l.nil? ? f : "%s - %s" % [f,l]`. `(f,*,l)` is the same as `(f,*arr,l)`, where `*` and `*arr` gobble up all the date strings between the first and last, exclusive.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Very very useful. Thanks again Cary for you great and kind help!